# How to send integer value to Serial communication in Visual C# to Arduino?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, arduino

I'm trying to create a GUI that read analog value from Arduino, and display them in zedGraph via GUI. I'm done with sending analog value and display it with GUI. But now I'm stuck with controlling when to start the reading via command to my servo. I can control the servo via serial monitor, but nothing happen when I try to control servo via Visual Studio. I want to make a program that when I clicked start button, the servo will rotate 180 degrees, and when I clicked stop, the servo will rotate to 10 degrees.

Sorry for a mess code, but I guess you can focus on `void serialEvent()` in Arduino code, and `arduino.WriteLine("180")` or `arduino.WriteLine("0")` in Visual Studio code.

Here's my Arduino code:

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <Servo.h>

#define StartConvert 0
#define ReadTemperature 1

Servo myservo;

const byte numReadings = 20;     //the number of sample times
byte ECsensorPin = A1;  //EC Meter analog output,pin on analog 1
byte DS18B20_Pin = 2; //DS18B20 signal, pin on digital 2
unsigned int AnalogSampleInterval=25,printInterval=1000,tempSampleInterval=1000;  //analog sample interval;serial print interval;temperature sample interval
unsigned int readings[numReadings];      // the readings from the analog input
byte index = 0;                  // the index of the current reading
unsigned long AnalogValueTotal = 0;                  // the running total
unsigned int AnalogAverage = 0,averageVoltage=0;                // the average
unsigned long AnalogSampleTime,printTime,tempSampleTime;
float temperature,ECcurrent; 
int val;

//Temperature chip i/o
OneWire ds(DS18B20_Pin);  // on digital pin 2

void setup() {
  //initialize serial communication with computer:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  //initialize all the readings to 0:
  for (byte thisReading = 0; thisReading < numReadings; thisReading++)
  readings[thisReading] = 0;
  TempProcess(StartConvert);   //let the DS18B20 start the convert
  AnalogSampleTime=millis();
  printTime=millis();
  tempSampleTime=millis();
  myservo.attach(9);
}


/**----------------------THIS IS ANALOG READING CODE--------------------
void loop() {

   //Every once in a while,sample the analog value and calculate the average.

  if(millis()-AnalogSampleTime>=AnalogSampleInterval)  
  {
    AnalogSampleTime=millis();
     // subtract the last reading:
    AnalogValueTotal = AnalogValueTotal - readings[index];
    // read from the sensor:
    readings[index] = analogRead(ECsensorPin);
    // add the reading to the total:
    AnalogValueTotal = AnalogValueTotal + readings[index];
    // advance to the next position in the array:
    index = index + 1;
    // if we're at the end of the array...
    if (index >= numReadings)
    // ...wrap around to the beginning:
    index = 0;
    // calculate the average:
    AnalogAverage = AnalogValueTotal / numReadings;
  }

  // Every once in a while,MCU read the temperature from the DS18B20 and then let the DS18B20 start the convert.
  // Attention:The interval between start the convert and read the temperature should be greater than 750 millisecond,or the temperature is not accurate!

   if(millis()-tempSampleTime>=tempSampleInterval) 
  {
    tempSampleTime=millis();
    temperature = TempProcess(ReadTemperature);  // read the current temperature from the  DS18B20
    TempProcess(StartConvert);                   //after the reading,start the convert for next reading
  }

   //Every once in a while,print the information on the serial monitor.

  if(millis()-printTime>=printInterval)
  {
    printTime=millis();
    averageVoltage=AnalogAverage*(float)5000/1024;

    //Serial.print("Analog value:");
    //Serial.print(AnalogAverage);   //analog average,from 0 to 1023
    //Serial.print("    Voltage:");
    //Serial.print(averageVoltage);  //millivolt average,from 0mv to 4995mV
    //Serial.print("mV    ");
    //Serial.print("temp:");
    //Serial.print(temperature);    //current temperature
    //Serial.print("^C     EC:");


    float TempCoefficient=1.0+0.0185*(temperature-25.0);    //temperature compensation formula: fFinalResult(25^C) = fFinalResult(current)/(1.0+0.0185*(fTP-25.0));
    float CoefficientVolatge=(float)averageVoltage/TempCoefficient;   
    if(CoefficientVolatge<150)Serial.println("No solution!");   //25^C 1413us/cm<-->about 216mv  if the voltage(compensate)<150,that is <1ms/cm,out of the range
    else if(CoefficientVolatge>3300)Serial.println("Out of the range!");  //>20ms/cm,out of the range
    else
    { 
      if(CoefficientVolatge<=448)ECcurrent=6.84*CoefficientVolatge-64.32;   //1ms/cm<EC<=3ms/cm
      else if(CoefficientVolatge<=1457)ECcurrent=6.98*CoefficientVolatge-127;  //3ms/cm<EC<=10ms/cm
      else ECcurrent=5.3*CoefficientVolatge+2278;                           //10ms/cm<EC<20ms/cm
      ECcurrent/=1000;    //convert us/cm to ms/cm
      float concentration = 0.0145*ECcurrent-0.0184;
      Serial.println(concentration,3);  //two decimal
      //Serial.println("ms/cm");
    }
  }
//----------------------THIS IS ANALOG READING CODE--------------------
}
**/ 

 void serialEvent(){        
    val =  Serial.parseInt();   //-----TRY READ INPUT FROM SERIAL MONITOR
    if(val != 0){
    myservo.write(val);
    }
 }

/*
ch=0,let the DS18B20 start the convert;ch=1,MCU read the current temperature from the DS18B20.
*/
float TempProcess(bool ch)
{
  //returns the temperature from one DS18B20 in DEG Celsius
  static byte data[12];
  static byte addr[8];
  static float TemperatureSum;
  if(!ch){
          if ( !ds.search(addr)) {
              Serial.println("no more sensors on chain, reset search!");
              ds.reset_search();
              return 0;
          }      
          if ( OneWire::crc8( addr, 7) != addr[7]) {
              Serial.println("CRC is not valid!");
              return 0;
          }        
          if ( addr[0] != 0x10 && addr[0] != 0x28) {
              Serial.print("Device is not recognized!");
              return 0;
          }      
          ds.reset();
          ds.select(addr);
          ds.write(0x44,1); // start conversion, with parasite power on at the end
  }
  else{  
          byte present = ds.reset();
          ds.select(addr);    
          ds.write(0xBE); // Read Scratchpad            
          for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { // we need 9 bytes
            data[i] = ds.read();
          }         
          ds.reset_search();           
          byte MSB = data[1];
          byte LSB = data[0];        
          float tempRead = ((MSB << 8) | LSB); //using two's compliment
          TemperatureSum = tempRead / 16;
    }
          return TemperatureSum;  
}
```

And here's my Visual C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//namespace untuk zedGrpah
using ZedGraph;
//namespace untuk class serial
using System.IO.Ports;
//namespace untuk melihat setting global komputer
using System.Globalization;


namespace Monitor_Suhu
{
    public partial class Form_utama : Form
    {
        /**Inisialisaisi arduino
         * Setup port serial dengan nama port COM3,
         * dan baud rate sebesar 115200.
         * **/
        SerialPort arduino = new SerialPort("COM3", 115200);        

        //waktu mulai dalam milidetik
        double waktuStart = 1000;


        //konstruktor
        public Form_utama()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        //event ketuka tombol start diklik
        private void btn_kontrol_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if(arduino.IsOpen){
              arduino.WriteLine("180");    //This command probably will send 180 to Arduino serial monitor
            }

            //start detak untuk mulai mengaktifkan grapher
            try
            {

                //arduino.WriteLine("on");
                //matikan tombol start
                btn_kontrol_start.Enabled = false;
                //nyalakan tombol stop
                btn_kontrol_stop.Enabled = true;
                //set batas waktu pembacaan serial sebelum dinyatakan gagal
                arduino.ReadTimeout = 1000;
                //set batas waktu penulisan serial
                arduino.WriteTimeout = 1000;


                //nyalakan detak
                Detak.Enabled = true;
                //mulai detak
                Detak.Start();  
            }
            catch (Exception gagal)
            {
                //Error handling
                //MessageBox.Show(gagal.ToString());
            }
        }


        //event ketika detak dimulai
        private void Detak_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                //Mulai komunikasi dengan arduino
                arduino.Open();

                //get item kurva pertama pada grafik
                LineItem kurvaKonsentrasi = zedGraphKonsentrasi.GraphPane.CurveList[0] as LineItem;

                //get PointPairList
                IPointListEdit listKonsentrasi = kurvaKonsentrasi.Points as IPointListEdit;

                //waktu yang terlewati
                double waktu = (Environment.TickCount - waktuStart) / 1000;

                //baca data konsentrasi yang dikirim arduino,
                //konversi data tersebut (string) ke double,
                //dan tambahkan ke listKonsentrasi
                float dataKonsentrasi = float.Parse(arduino.ReadLine(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                listKonsentrasi.Add(waktu, Convert.ToDouble(dataKonsentrasi));

                String konsentrasi = dataKonsentrasi.ToString();
                data_tb.AppendText( Environment.NewLine +konsentrasi);
                //Tutup komunikasi dengan arduino
                arduino.Close();

                //Buat scale X tetap rolling dalam interval 30 detik, dengan satu
                //langkah besar antara nilai X maksimal dan akhir dari axis
                Scale xScale = zedGraphKonsentrasi.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale;
                if (waktu > xScale.Max - xScale.MajorStep)
                {
                    xScale.Max = waktu + xScale.MajorStep;
                    xScale.Min = xScale.Max - 30.0;
                }

                // Pastikan Y axis di scale ulang untuk mengakomodir data aktual
                zedGraphKonsentrasi.AxisChange();

                // Redraw paksa
                zedGraphKonsentrasi.Invalidate();

                String tampil = arduino.ReadLine();
                data_tb.Text = tampil;

            }
            catch (Exception gagal)
            {
                //error handling
                //tutup komunikasi dengan arduino jika masih terhubung
                if (arduino.IsOpen)
                {
                    arduino.Close();
                }
                //MessageBox.Show(gagal.ToString());
            }

        }

        //event ketika tombol stop diklik
        private void btn_kontrol_stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(arduino.IsOpen){
              arduino.WriteLine("0");         //This command probably will send 0 to Arduino serial monitor
            }

            try
            {
              // arduino.WriteLine("off");
                //nyalakan kembali tombol start
                btn_kontrol_start.Enabled = true;
                //matikan tombol stop
                btn_kontrol_stop.Enabled = false;
                //stop detak
                Detak.Stop();
                //matikan detak
                Detak.Enabled = false;
                //jika komunikasi masih terbuka, tutup komunikasi
                if (arduino.IsOpen)
                {
                    arduino.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception gagal)
            {
                //error handling
                MessageBox.Show(gagal.ToString());
            }
        }

        //event ketika form utama dibuka
        private void Form_utama_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //catat waktu pertama sebagai referensi
                waktuStart = Environment.TickCount;

                //Inisialisasi ZedGraph
                GraphPane grafikKonsentrasi = zedGraphKonsentrasi.GraphPane;
                grafikKonsentrasi.Title.Text = "Concentration Graph";
                grafikKonsentrasi.XAxis.Title.Text = "Time (Second)";
                grafikKonsentrasi.YAxis.Title.Text = "Concentration (mol/l)";

                //Simpan 120 point. Pada 500 ms sampel rate.
                //RollingPointPairList adalah class penyimpanan yang efisien 
                //dengan tetap merolling kumpulan point data tanpa perlu
                //men-shift nilai data apapun
                RollingPointPairList listKonsentrasi = new RollingPointPairList(120);

                //Inisialisasi kurva
                LineItem kurvaKonsentrasi = grafikKonsentrasi.AddCurve("Concentration", listKonsentrasi, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);

            }
            catch (Exception gagal)
            {
                //error handling
                //MessageBox.Show(gagal.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string pathfile = @"C:\Users\ajis.aprl\Documents\TA bgt\data_GUI\";
                string filename = "concentration.txt";
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(pathfile + filename, data_tb.Text);
                MessageBox.Show("Data has been saved to " + pathfile, "Save File");
            }
            catch (Exception ex3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex3.Message, "Error");
            }
        }




    }
}
```

Comment: You can simplify your solution dramatically by using the Firmata library on the Arduino and connect to the board by using e.g. this library: https://github.com/SolidSoils/Arduino.